# Installing Node packages globally without internet connection

Tags: node.js, pm2, forever

I am working on Windows Server 2012 R2, but external internet connection is restricted in my Org. So i can not install any NPM packages on server directly.

I want to install pm2 OR forever packages globally so that all the user profiles(admin and users) can access that from any directory.

Please guide me in this case.

Comment: Did you ask your IT or the person in charge for your concern?

Comment: Yes, they dont give any satisfactory answer and denied to install packages from any open source.

Comment: Well. Did you then talk to your supervisor?

Comment: I talked to everyone concerned but they all are bound by the rules and restrictions. I got a restricted server profile in which i dont have complete access and i have to write some script which runs my Node.js program automatically every time server restart.

Comment: You may use a USB key to get the packages into your computer.

Comment: You can copy `%appdata%\npm` from another computer using USB. Also, are you sure you are not bound by the same rules and restrictions ? It might not be ok to install such packages.

Answer (score 0):

From another pc with internet connection, you can download the source code from github. For example, for pm2 it is : https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

After downloading the source code, you need to look into the package.json file and download all the dependency source code too. ( One easy way to do all of above is to use npm to fetch pm2 in a local directory then copy the pm2 along with all dependencies to a USB)

Transfer files into a directory of your server workstation using USB or any other suitable means.

Add the pm2/bin directory to your PATH.

Test with `pm2 -v` from command line to ensure PATH addition is correct.